# Initializing Google Play Games Client in Android with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I had Google Play Services working some time ago, but it seems that after the upgrade from unity 2018.1 to 2018.2 it stopped working. (I'm not sure if the upgrade caused this)

In unity logs I can see:

```
Starting Auth with token client.
!!![Play Games Plugin DLL]07/17/18 15:49:08 +02:00 WARNING: Creating new PlayGamesPlatform
Building GPG services, implicitly attempts silent auth
```

and than app crashes

In Pre-launch report I can see that it crashes on app start when(from logcat):

```
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897): Exception encountered by: Thread[main,5,main]. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897):   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzv(Unknown Source)
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897):   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzakg(Unknown Source)
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897):   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
07-19 05:29:53.387: E/MonitoringInstr(20897):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

followed by:

```
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):   Thread[UnityMain,5,main]
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:392)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):   Thread[InstrumentationConnectionThread,5,main]
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):   Thread[ReferenceQueueDaemon,5,system]
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:162)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):   Thread[Thread-3086,4,main]
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:418)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:540)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.unity3d.player.UnityWebRequest.runSafe(Unknown Source)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     com.unity3d.player.UnityWebRequest.run(Unknown Source)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):   Thread[HeapTaskDaemon,5,system]
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native Method)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:370)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):   Thread[FinalizerWatchdogDaemon,5,system]
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:985)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(Daemons.java:288)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:299)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:247)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):   Thread[main,5,main]
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:522)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.getThreadState(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:194)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.dumpThreadStateToOutputs(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:191)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.onException(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:188)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onException(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:117)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation$3.uncaughtException(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):   Thread[GAC_Executor[0],5,main]
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):     java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
07-19 05:29:53.397: E/THREAD_STATE(20897):
```

Also from Pre-launch it has no errors on Pixel 2 phone.(maybe because it's the only one running android P preview)

I tried:

- reinstalling android studio with sdk
- re-importing google play games for unity from github
- changing google play resolver settings to use older .aars (tested on 10.6.2 | 10.0.1 | 10.0.4)
- making changes to AndroidMainfest.xml as shown in other threads, but those solutions mostly failed at build due to overriding from already existing entries(which were the same as the ones I was trying to add)

I don't have any other ideas of what I can try to get it working again. So any suggestions are appreciated.